# How do i create Uistackview and add it into a view?

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode8

@Ali

how do i create a uistackview and use into my view? ive got an image showing what i mean

[Image - UIstackview](http://blasze.tk/PAZDJ6)

Comment: Your image link does not work

Answer (score 0):

```
let stackView = UIStackView()
addSubview(view: stackView)
addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(...probably constrain all 4 sides or however you want to here.
```